# Package '@angular/core' is not a dependency. while updating angular 8 to angular 9

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, angular8, angular9

While updating angular 8 project to angular 9 , getting error

```
✔ Package successfully installed.
Using package manager: 'npm'
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 0 dependencies.
Package '@angular/core' is not a dependency.
```

command I use

```
ng update @angular/core@9 @angular/cli@9 --force
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Run command

```
npm i
```

then it works

Comment: Yes, if you don't have the node_modules folder, it won't work. Ensure you resolve any issues with "npm install" first.

Comment: Could you give a quick explanation for why this works?

Comment: i had same problem , in my case i had to run " npm i " in all sub project(i used angular work space)

Comment: This worked, upgrading 14.0.3 to 14.2.8.