# "'@angular/core' is not a dependency" when upgrading Angular 12 to 13

Tags: angular

My problem persists when I give the command

```
ng update @angular/core@13 @angular/cli@13
```

which tells me:

```
daniel@ICHIGA:~$ ng update @angular/core@13 @angular/cli@13

The installed Angular CLI version is outdated.
Installing a temporary Angular CLI version 13.3.11 to perform the update.
✔ Package successfully installed.
Using package manager: 'npm'
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 3 dependencies.
Package '@angular/core' is not a dependency.
```

What I want is to install Angular 16 and depending on what I know I have to install 13 to 14 and so on

I tried installing other versions hoping it would work but the same or worse.

Comment: I deleted `1.` as you've tagged this [tag:angular], which is 2+, but maybe you _do_ mean 1.x [tag:angularjs]? _Do_ you have `@angular/core` installed? Give a [mre].

Comment: Hi. Looks like you have only 3 dependencies. Can you show package.json?

Comment: I don't know how to show it sorry

Comment: answer can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69765700/5211837